# Is this "in the hearts of every creature" right? why?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

1. Is this "in the hearts of every creature" right? why?
2. Is this "in the heart of all those..." right? why?

Comment: You will hear the mismatch of number in the speech of native speakers, but "heart" would go better with "every" and "hearts" with "all those".

Answer (score 1):

"Every" is a group noun like "family", and "team".

So... which form for group nouns? That depends on whether you speak AmE or BrE.

For AmE, group nouns form collectives (think of The Borg) which are then treated as single units. So: "The family is ready to go", "The team is dressed in green", and so on.

For BrE, group nouns get the plural form: "The family are ready to go", &etc.

So to your question:

> 1. Is this "in the hearts of every creature" right? why?

Not for me; I speak AmE. Should be "in the heart of every creature"

> 1. Is this "in the heart of all those..." right? why?

Not for anyone. "All those" does not form a collective, so: "in the hearts of all those"

Why the difference in group noun status? I can't give you an answer, only a guess: "All those who..." is an ad-hoc grouping that's swept together with a word, and falls apart in the next sentence.